# Convert textdata from website request to pandas dataframe efficiently

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I have the following website athand and am trying to pull historical data from it.
http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvol20180801.txt

My initial approach would be as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

url ="http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvol20180801.txt"
response_data = requests.get(url).content
dfRaw= pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(response_data))
```

The output is below and needs a complete rework to be workable with. i.e. columns are wrongly defined, indices don't look good, etc.

```
Out[72]: 
                                   Date|Symbol|ShortVolume|ShortExemptVolume|TotalVolume|Market
20180801|A|127212|14|658064|Q                                                       N          
20180801|AA|514915|817|1549350|Q                                                    N          
20180801|AABA|975797|370|3608955|Q                                                  N          
20180801|AAC|43229|0|93929|Q                                                        N          
20180801|AADR|3213|0|9620|Q                                                         N          
                                                                              ...          
20180801|ZUMZ|85580|0|150959|Q                                                      N          
20180801|ZUO|152012|100|293146|Q                                                    N          
20180801|ZYME|6706|0|28133|Q                                                        N          
20180801|ZYNE|85036|0|202011|Q                                                      N          
7676                                                                              NaN
```

As I am iterating through years on finra, I'd prefer to not mangle with pandas after pd.read_csv() and be as performant as possible in extracting the data and getting a clean dataframe.

How could I achieve this without changing the dataframe after this code? Is my approach suiteable? Should I look into different libraries like beautifulsoup or other webscraping ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sufficient :

```py
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvol20180801.txt', sep='|')
```

Comment: Tried read_html, never thought about read_csv... Always fascinating how powerful pandas is. Thanks